# how to solve the problem with markers overlapping each other when hovering the mouse in highmaps(highcharts)?

Tags: highcharts

how to make the marker "moscow" by default be placed behind the marker "tula", and also when hovering over the marker "moscow" it remains behind the marker "tula" and is partially highlighted?

my code: [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-map-employees-project-forked-mkplk5)

you can consider other approaches to placing markers on the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that you need to overwrite the graphic element of the moskva or tula markers at chart `load` event, `onMouseOver()` and `onMouseOut()` functions as well.

Here is the example modification you can base on:

When you loop throught the points add the conditional as follows:

```
 if (el.id === "tula") {
      el.graphic.attr({
              zIndex: 100,
          });
    }
```

And at the mouseOver/mouseOut functions the following modification with the opacity change:

```
 if (this.id === "moskva") {
        this.graphic.attr({
          opacity: 0.5,
          zIndex: -100,
        });
      }
```

**Demo:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-map-employees-project-forked-w7pxnr?file=/src/components/Chart.vue

Comment: unfortunately binding to received names/identifiers (el.id === "tula" and others) is not suitable, because it is planned that users will use their own lists of cities, ie. there is no way to improve the display through the code.
I would also be happy with such a temporary solution: is it possible to somehow hide (remove) the inscription "1k" from the "tula" marker when hovering over the "Moscow" marker (without binding to static city names/identifiers)?
maybe you can somehow influence the z-index of just the numbers (1K, 10K, 7, 2.5K, 9, etc.) for all markers?

Comment: I think there is technological issue there and it's related to the different groups of the markers and dataLabels and how the svg is positioned. In case when we have two custom symbols (svg) they landed to he one group of markers. DataLabels are grouped separately. You can compare following case studies: MapPin as a custom symbol:https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v3eqLmfa/ ;MapPin as a dataLabels shape (html true): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2cw4g3ez/ ;MapPin as a dataLabels shape (html false): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xo1e74Lk/ ;

Comment: As a solution you can try the MapPin as a dataLabels: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yL94atuh/

Comment: Thanks you. Your third option seems to be what I need. I would also like to enable clustering, but unfortunately that doesn't work. 1) Is it possible to make clustering work?  2) how to display text description (labels) side by side
    with a marker ([link](https://ltdfoto.ru/images/2023/07/17/5.png))?  Demo: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/891obr35/4)

Comment: 1) You will need to declare your data as an array of objects 2) Provided image doesn't work, but to move text,edit the `dataLabels.formatter` Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x4husvrk/